# DataGrid Row checkbox filed Not updated in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi i m having one datagrid...that have one check box field...whenever i check the check box that time that row will be inserted in database...but check box value is not set true value...it always return false value...i m using C# asp.net 2003 version..please help me...

Comment: DataGrid or GridView?  Is ViewState on?

Comment: ^^ He is using ASP.NET 1.1 (as he stated 2003), so ideally it would be a DataGrid only..

Answer (score 1):

If you data bind the grid in Page_Load, maybe you don't check for IsPostBack, so, your grid gets rebound and all previous changes like check are not persisted.

```
if(! Page.IsPostBack)  
{
    // Data bind the grid  
}
```

Another possible reason is how you try to retrieve the checbox.

We really need to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<dgpayslip.Items.Count;i++) { CheckBox chkEditable; chkEditable = (CheckBox)dgpayslip.Items[i].FindControl("chkbox"); if(chkEditable.Checked==true) { INSProc.InsertPayslipTemplate(compcode,category,template,user); Page.RegisterStartupScript("alrt","<script>alert('New Template Added');</script>"); } }

Comment: Cool, how did you solve it? Did one of the answers solve your question (please mark then)? or did you find the way elsewhere (please post an answer yourself then)?

Answer (score 0):

Its not immediately clear what your problem is. But if I had to guess, since ASP.NET 1.1. doesn't support two-way data binding, I would start with the code that reads the data from the form and updates your data source.

Comment: i m not trying two way binding...i just click the check box in datagrid row...but the check box value is false only...